# Mudar a propriedade DrawableLeft de um TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Eu tenho um SimpleAdapter que eu uso em um listview para mostrar dados que vem do banco.
Segue o código

```
Map<String, String> map;
for(int i = 0;i < buscaCombustivel.getCount();i++) {
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("idItem", buscaCombustivel.getString(buscaCombustivel.getColumnIndex("id")));
    map.put("text1", buscaCombustivel.getString(buscaCombustivel.getColumnIndex("dataEntrada")));
    map.put("desc","Litros: " + buscaCombustivel.getString(buscaCombustivel.getColumnIndex("litrosEntrada")) + " | Valor unitário: " +
            buscaCombustivel.getString(buscaCombustivel.getColumnIndex("valorUnitarioEntrada")) + " | Valor total: " +
            buscaCombustivel.getString(buscaCombustivel.getColumnIndex("valorTotalEntrada")) + "\n");
    list.add(map);
    buscaCombustivel.moveToNext();
}
SimpleAdapter adapterDropDown = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list, R.layout.custom_list, new String[] { "text1", desc", "idItem" }, new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.desc, R.id.idItem });
listDados.setAdapter(adapterDropDown);
```

O R.id.text1, usado no SimpleAdapter, possui uma propriedade chamada DrawableLeft no seu xml. Eu precisava mudar essa propriedade dependendo de um certo valor que vier do banco de dados. É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Sim! Geralmente você coloca uma imagem no DrawableLeft. Está chegando uma url da imagem do banco de dados?!

Comment: Não, é um drawable mesmo...
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/tic14"

Comment: Por que você não cria um custom adapter e define o xml que você quer? É bem simples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o método `getView` no seu `SimpleAdapter` e o `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` definindo no primeiro argumento o *drawable* específico, que no seu caso seria o `R.drawable.tic14`. Isso garantirá que o *drawable* será inserido à esquerda do seu `TextView`.  Veja um exemplo:

```
SimpleAdapter adapterDropDown = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list,
    R.layout.custom_list, new String[] {
        "text1",
        desc,
        idItem
    }, new int[] {
        R.id.text1, R.id.desc, R.id.idItem
    }) {

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

        int imgResource = R.drawable.tic14;
        text1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(imgResource, 0, 0, 0);

        return view;
    };
};
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho!